# how can i upload course and user with its id on moodle

Tags: moodle

I want to upload course using upload courses menu.
and i want to import the id with the other fields.
I tried `"id","shortname","fullname","category"` as a filed on the csv.But  it uses incremented id instead.
Oh and i want the same thing for user too.

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done - all ids in Moodle are automatically generated, in order to make sure they always uniquely identify the item (course, user, etc).

Instead of trying to identify the course by id, you should look at identifying it by shortname or idnumber.

Comment: But i am going to import the participant list from another database.I have a table which has course Id and user Id. I was planning to import that table into `mdl_enrol` .So first I have to import user table and course table with their id.Since that is their connection.So what if i stopped the incremental property off?

Comment: Try flat file enrolment https://docs.moodle.org/en/Flat_file and using user/course idnumbers.

Comment: That's very helpful.Thank you! But it says `The file should be structured with the ... user ID number, and course ID number` . And i have that relation with the old ids. and the record is more than 10k. So i can't use the the newly generated id.

Comment: ok it says `user idnumber - idnumber in the user table NB not id` so  i think i can import idnumber. right?

Comment: yes, idnumber and id are different fields. See also https://docs.moodle.org/en/Upload_courses and https://docs.moodle.org/en/Upload_users - you can use them to create courses, users and enrolments from csv files